# Get an attributes value from within the attribute

Tags: perl, metaprogramming, moose

In the Moose Extension I'm writing I'm trying to access the attributes value from within the attribute, without going through the accessor, but  I can't seem to get this right.

I'm trying to be able to write this code

```
{
    package Test;
    use Moose;
    use MooseX::RemoteName; #provides magic

    has attr0 => (
        isa         => 'Bool',
        is          => 'ro',
        default     => sub { 1 },
        serializer  => sub {
           my $s = shift;
           return $s->get_value( $s ) ? 'Y' : 'N';
        }, 
    );

    has attr1 => (
       isa => 'Str',
       is  => 'ro',
    )
}
```

so that I can then do (from my test)

```
my $t0 = Test->new({ attr1 => 'foo' });

isa_ok my $attr0 = $t0->meta->get_attribute('attr0'), 'Class::MOP::Attribute';
is $attr0->serialized,  'Y',    'remote_name serializes';

isa_ok my $attr1 = $t0->meta->get_attribute('attr1'), 'Class::MOP::Attribute';
is $attr1->serialized,  'foo',    'remote_name serializes'; # undef
```

This is what I'm trying in the extension

```
has serializer => (
    isa       => 'CodeRef',
    is        => 'ro',
    lazy      => 1,
    default   => sub {
        return sub {
            my $arg = shift;
            return $arg->get_value( $arg->associated_class );
        }
    },
);

sub serialized {
    my $self = shift;

    my $coderef = $self->serializer;

    return &$coderef( $self );
}
```

Comment: I think the serializer can just call the accessor.  There's no danger of the accessor calling the serializer that I can see.

Comment: only problem I have with that is that in some cases I was going to undefine the reader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problems appear to be two fold, my anonymous subroutines weren't done right, and I needed to pass the instance of the object to the anonymous subroutine.

This seems to be working in my Moose Extension

```
has serializer => (
    predicate => 'has_serializer',
    traits    => ['Code'],
    is        => 'ro',
    default   => sub {
        return sub {
            my ( $self, $instance ) = @_;
            return $self->get_value( $instance );
        }
    },
    handles   => {
        serializing => 'execute_method',
    },
);

sub serialized {
    my ( $self, $instance ) = @_;

    return $self->serializing( $instance );
}
```

which then allows me to write the following (slightly different)

```
package Test;
use Moose;
use MooseX::RemoteName;

has attr0 => (
    isa        => 'Bool',
    is         => 'ro',
    lazy       => 1,
    default    => sub { 1 },
    serializer => sub {
        my ( $attr, $instance ) = @_;
        return $attr->get_value( $instance ) ? 'Y' : 'N';
    },
);
```

which will pass this test without issue

```
subtest t0 => sub {
    my $t = Test->new;

    is $t->attr0, 1, 'attr0 is 1';

    isa_ok my $attr0 = $t->meta->get_attribute('attr0'), 'Class::MOP::Attribute';

    is $attr0->serialized( $t ),  'Y',    'attr0 serializes';
    isa_ok $t, 'Test';
};
```

I think I can live passing the instance in, though I'm not entirely sure why `get_value` needs that.

Comment: The reason `get_value()` needs the instance is because that's where the data is kept, that's what an *instance* is ... it's data bound to a class. Also this isn't really currying. You're just creating an anonymous sub, currying involves a bit more than that (you'd have to be creating a closure over one or more values which you're not doing anywhere in here that I can tell).

Comment: You are confusing your object instances. `$attr` isn't an instance of `Test`, it's an instance of `Moose::Meta::Attribute`. It will still need the proper data structure passed into it (the instance of `Test` in this case) so that it can dig out the proper value.